# How to check tree of directories for changes efficiently after termination and restart of program?

Tags: java, persistence

I am writing a program that loads a library of data from the disk. It scans recursively through each folder specified by the user, reads the necessary metadata from each file, and then saves that in the program's library into a data structure that is suitable for display and manipulation by the user.

For a reasonable sized data set, this process takes 5-10 minutes. On the high end I could imagine it taking half an hour.

It also sets up a [watcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) for each directory in the tree, so if anything is changed after the initial scan while the program is running, that changed file or folder can be re-scanned and the library updated with the new data.

When the program terminates, the library data structure is serialized to disk, and then loaded back in at the beginning of the next session.

This leaves one gap that needed to be addressed -- **if files are changed between sessions, there is no way to know about those changes.**

The solution currently implemented is, when the program is launched and the persisted data is loaded, to then rescan the entire file structure and compare the scanned information to the loaded data, and if anything is different, to replace it.

Given that the rescan reads the metadata of each file and reloads everything, just to discard it after confirming nothing has changed, this seems like a very inefficient method to me.

**Here is my question:** I'd like to find some way to shortcut this re-scan process so I don't have to read all of the metadata back in and do a full rescan. Instead, it would be nice if there were a way to ask a folder *"have your contents changed at all since the last time I saw you? If so, let me rescan you, otherwise, I won't bother rescanning."*

One idea that occurs to me is to take a checksum of the folder's contents and store that in the database, and then compare the hashes during the re-scan.

Before I implement this solution, does anyone have a recommendation on how to accomplish this in a better way (or any advice for how to efficiently take the hash of a directory with java)?

Comment: manage a metastore file to check tree of directories on basic of name, size, when created and last modified date, also create another log file which will be created when a fresh scan starts, and provide that session a jobid, manage the jobid details in metastore file, like when the jobid starts, finishes different stages, and ends with their timestamp, so whenever any jobid process terminates in between, and your program starts again, it will check for the last job id, its start, different stages and end, if end tag not found, access the jobid log file, as you wish scan or leave those tree dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store timestamp on shutdown, then just do `find -mnewer`?

Answer (score 1):

The most practical way is to traverse the file tree checking for files with a timestamp newer than when your application stopped.  For example

```
find root-dir -mnewer`
```

though if you did it that way you may run into race conditions.  (It would be better to do it in Java ... as you reinstantiate the watchers.)

There are a couple of caveats:

- Scanning a file tree takes time.  The larger the tree, the longer it takes.  If you are talking millions of files it could take hours, just to look at the timestamps.
- Timestamps are not bombproof:

  - there can be issues if there are "discontinuities" in the system clock, or
  - there can be issues if some person or program with admin privilege tweaks file timestamps.

> One idea that occurs to me is to take a checksum of the folder's contents and store that in the database, and then compare the hashes during the re-scan.

It would take much longer to compute checksums or hashes of files.  The only way that would be feasible is if the operating system itself was to *automatically* compute and record a file checksum or hash each time a file was updated.  (That would be a significant performance hit on all file / directory write operations ...)